# The comment field under election candidates is too large

Tags: bug, design, election

The comment textarea element for a new comment (`<textarea class="s-textarea [...]">`) under each candidate's nomination is overflowing its parent div on the right, and is conflicting with the div to the right that contains the help link and submit button (`<div class="d-flex fd-column [...]">`):

[image: Comment box overflowing the parent div]

This is due to the padding applied in two places:

- `padding: 8px 10px` that's applied in **primary.css** to all input elements
- `padding .7em;` that's applied to `.s-input, .s-textarea` in **stacks.css**

I am using Firefox 62.0 on Windows 7.

Comment: i'm also getting this on Chrome Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit), Windows 10

Answer (score -1):

Good catch.  This isn't something that can be fixed in an individual stack, it should probably be brought to the attention of the Admins at [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), where they deal with sitewide issues.

Comment: Actually part of it does need to be fixed for this specific stack; `primary.css` is specific to Movies.SE. I haven't looked on MSE for a report on this issue yet (MSO is just for SO issues despite originally being network-wide).

Comment: As a Mod on the Music stack, I know we have no control over coding issues.  We're just there to moderate, which I assume is how this stack is run too.

Comment: Right; I wouldn't expect the mods to fix a bug. The developers, however, do check for [meta-tag:bug] reports on all meta sites.

Comment: It probably *will* get fixed once the site theme gets ported to the new unified SE design architecture, anyway.

Comment: FWIW any meta bug report or feature request can be posted anywhere regardless of if it only affects one stack or all of them.

Comment: [meta.se], not [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).